# How to install a certificate automatically

Tags: browser, certificate, ssl-certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I would like to know how to generate a certificate and make it to be imported automatically to all main browser (chrome, firefox, ie etc...). Should I upload this certificate to a public CA or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you generate self sign certificate then the browser will not recognize it as a trusted certificate. You have to get your certificate from trusted CA or from its reseller and you need to follow online procedure for certificate generation. Certificate issued by Certificate Authority will be recognized by 99.9% browsers including chrome, Firefox etc. You do not need to upload the certificate any where except the server for which you have taken a certificate.